# Automatic detection of copied code

Tags: discussion

**Update** based on early comments:

- I'm just wondering if we have such a feature, as my original question says.

---

Is there any feature we have that attempts to identify questions based on the same codebase, often a tutorial that many beginners may have copied from before running into problems?

I stumbled on this guy earlier, doing some Android spring-cleaning:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648522/getting-null-pointer-exception-in-music-player

While reading, I realised the code was way more advanced than the OP's grasp of the concepts.

So a bit of the google using some phrases from the code and I came up with 3 other questions based on the same tutorial ([possible original code from here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)):

- [Activity is never launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547032/activity-is-never-launched)
- [weird android mediaplayer error - Error (-38,0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450435/weird-android-mediaplayer-error-error-38-0)
- [List view not sending exact list item clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021476/list-view-not-sending-exact-list-item-clicked)

---

It got me wondering if we have a way to detect this - although its more an intellectual question than something pragmatic or useful. Hence the "discussion" tag.

But perhaps it could feed back into our duplicates algorithm somehow.

Comment: What if it's exactly the same code but a totally different question?

Comment: That's fine. My question is "do we have that feature?" and the context is "I'd be interested to know if we do"

Comment: And if we detect it, what do we do?

Comment: @Joe Perhaps I should tag my question as "feature-request"? Then I could propose that if we detect it, it would increase the score used to determine possible duplicates, in our duplicate engine.

Comment: As far as I am aware there are (or used to be) heuristics to detect duplication of post text (possibly including anything in a code block) within SO, but nothing to check outside that domain (as that is a pointless task - copied code/text doesn't necessarily indicate a problem). What I noticed/read was a long time ago though so treat it as anecdotal until proven otherwise.

Comment: @slugster the duplication of posted code is what I'm talking about. I don't think it is used anymore, or perhaps only contributes a small amount to the duplication score. Since the above examples use the same code base (and are not duplicates at all).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a feature within the SE software that I know off that can do this.

I do know some smart attempts to detect plagiarized posts

- [How can SEDE be utilized to find potential plagiarism on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306187/how-can-sede-be-utilized-to-find-potential-plagiarism-on-stack-overflow/306188#306188)
- [How should I report plagiarized tag wikis?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289246/how-should-i-report-plagiarized-tag-wikis)

and some even download and import the [Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) to run these searches locally.

No matter how succesful these efforts are, it still needs some human intervention and judgement to verify the result and take the correct action. That is basiclly in line with the answers on: [Can we get statistics on how much plagiarism is handled by the mods?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307665/can-we-get-statistics-on-how-much-plagiarism-is-handled-by-the-mods)

This gets even more complex and resoure consuming if you reduce the copied pieces to only code blocks and I would expect the number of false positives to be higher.

There are some tools that can help but the best option is still having enough eyes on the new posts in tags you follow to weed out the duplicates and spot the users that forget to add proper attribution to their copied code blocks, much in the same fashion you already did.