# How should I report plagiarized tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, flags, tag-wiki, plagiarism

> This has been asked before, [How to deal with plagiarized content in tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256436/how-to-deal-with-plagiarized-content-in-tag-wikis). However, that question was closed as a duplicate of other questions that don't really answer the question.

---

It's easy to write up a [quick SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291753) that simply digs up random tag wiki excerpts. One can then look through this list, choose one at random, Google a couple sentences from it, and find a plagiarism source.

Sometimes it's unclear which direction the plagiarism went, but sometimes I can verify that Stack Overflow has the plagiarized content. This means that *we stole from someone else*, without attribution, and the system didn't catch it.

I don't have 20,000 reputation, and thus I can't single-handedly roll these back. I tried flagging one of the plagiarizer's posts a couple weeks ago, but I haven't heard anything back on the flag.

Before I unleash a bunch of these flags, I'd like the verify that this is actually what I should be doing.

Is it okay to simply flag one of the user's posts with a custom message explaining the situation? Is there another way that I *should* do it?

Comment: Flags are a reasonable way to ask someone with the necessary reputation/powers to take a look at something if you are unable to do so.

Comment: I don't think you can flag tag wikis. I guess you could just flag _any_ post instead.

Comment: @jimsug That's what I do, but I want to make sure that this is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plagiarized content in a tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311383/plagiarized-content-in-a-tag-wiki)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a (down voted) answer on [Plagiarized content in a tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311390/578411) that I still think is the best way to fix these kind wiki's.

One other concrete example where I used the proposed technique was on [How to handle tag wikis with promotional content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312219/578411) where I asked the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room to help out. They have some 20K-ers as regulars that are capable of judging the plagiarism and re-write the wiki into a much better shape.

I personally find it strange that the community can change wiki's but if it needs moderation your only option is to call for a moderator. Fixing takes effort if you want to roll-forward and if you want to roll-back you either need a 20K-er or 6 robo-reviewers (where are they when you need them).

My suggestion would be to consult in a chatroom that have 20K-ers around. The [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is such room. There they can determine if and how the content should be fixed. Some rooms are also frequented by moderators so those rooms have all possible routes available. When a 20K-er agrees to fix the wiki you don't need a flag. If the plagiarism is of reasonable size (I'm open for any number) you can still flag for a moderator to investigate the user based on the evidence gathered.