# Plagiarized content in a tag wiki

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, plagiarism

There are several questions dealing with this issue, but no clear answers. The tag [ssh.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh.net) contains content plagiarized from the [ssh.net home page](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/).

My attempt to revert was [rejected 3-2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10375900). I can only conclude that three people didn't bother to read the edit summary, since I stated quite clearly what I was doing, why, and what had been plagiarized.

I could try editing it again and hope for better reviewers, but who wants a bunch of rejected edits? So what should I do? You can't flag a tag.

Comment: Why did you try to remove the list? I could see reverting the two sentences which now became a copy-paste, but a list is a list. You can't rewrite that list in any way that would make it *not* "plagiarism" in the sense of it was copy-pasted.

Comment: Tag wikis exist to be filled with plagiarized content.

Comment: @animuson That makes sense. I don't know anything about the topic so I didn't think I could improve it, but I suppose anything can be rewritten. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyBanks It does seem like it sometimes, doesn't it :p

Comment: I really don't understand this.  Placing someone's *ad copy* into the tag for *their product* isn't plagiarism.  If you managed to get a hold on someone over at ssh.net, drug them over here and forced them to fill in the tag, *they'd probably copypaste the information on their homepage into the tag*.  Their words about their product.  You know what they probably wouldn't like?  You trying to interpret their words when describing their product.  You're likely to get something wrong, and that may cause them issues (e.g., "but it says you can do this!").

Comment: @Will: Apart from the plagiarism issue, **ad copy does not make a good tag wiki**.

Comment: @BenVoigt "ad copy" *can*, if it tells you all you need to know.

Comment: @Will: As I said in my answer, ad copy may be useful to someone deciding whether or not to use a certain library / service / whatever.  But it is not useful to people answering questions (people with experience and expertise from actually using the library should answer) or asking questions (since askers are supposed to attempt to solve the problem before asking, they've already decided to use the library, at least in this proof-of-concept code they have a question about -- questions about what the library is capable of are off topic here)

Comment: Y'all taking this "ad copy" phrase **way too literally**.  If I have a website for my API, it contains everything I want people in the world to know about my work.  If someone copies that into the related tag's wiki, and links to my website, that makes me **happy**.  Tag wikis are for letting people know what the tag is about and are useless to those in the know. @BenVoigt the only thing an asker/answerer would use the tag for is to 1) identify answerable questions (tag text) or 2) verify the tag identity (tag excerpt). The body is only useful to those without any knowledge of the subject.

Comment: Does [this license](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/license) apply to the material on the web page as well as to the source code? If so, it should be possible to use the text in the tag wiki without violating the license. (Whether it's practical and/or desirable to do is another question.)

Comment: To those who marked this question a duplicate, I will grant you that Undo's postings are more comprehensive, but did you notice both of them came *after* this one? You can hardly blame me for not having consulted questions that *did not yet exist!*

Answer (score 26):

You did exactly the right thing.

The [problem with copy+pasta from vendor sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309384/103167) is that it ends up parroting non-factual claims like "best performance possible". That's expected in marketing-speak, not acceptable for a tag wiki here on Stack Overflow.

Deleting the plagiarized list was also fine, since it is a maintenance burden to keep it from becoming out of date (and most likely already is... none of the frameworks listed are latest versions, and although I have no evidence that said library works on .NET 4.6 or Windows Phone 10, I'd be surprised if it triggers a backcompat bug).

The list of compatible frameworks is nowhere near the most important thing to people asking and answering questions about the library (it might be to someone evaluating it), and in any case it was only one extra click away on the project's homepage.

So no, the plagiarism edit made things worse, and your suggestion was a solid improvement. Reviewers who rejected it need a prod from the moderators to take a second look.

Comment: _"Reviewers who rejected it need a prod from the moderators to take a second look"_ -- I agree, but if comments are second-class citizens on Stack Overflow, tags sometimes seem like third-class, as there's no good way to notify a moderator about tag problems. You can flag some completely unrelated post and provide a detailed description, but that's pretty ugly as solutions go. I'm not even sure what a moderator would ultimately do to address such a flag anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options, both leading to successful removal of the plagiarized content, nothing that was stolen is kept:

- roll-back
- roll-forward

#### Roll-back

To undo plagiarism you're often forced to make a major edit by removing a lot of content. Somehow we trained the reviewers to reject such major edits (not often because they appear to be audits).

If you feel your only option is to remove a substantial amount of content, consider seeking help from a chat room where it's members are prepared to help getting the review task approved. By sharing the review task the members will handle that task.
(do note that any organized moderation is still subject to site policies and shouldn't be abused). The chatroom can probably also help in verifying if other options are viable.

#### Roll-forward

As you have to suggest an edit you could look into extending and improving substantially while **removing** the plagiarized content and adding attribution if their license allows for it.
That should get such suggested-edits gets passed reviewers because the wiki gets richer in content and as a result of that the plagiarism is gone. And an improved wiki is also helpful for future visitors.

The following is an example of how such a roll-forward edit could look like:

> ssh.net is an open-source .Net port of the Java Sharp.SSH library and is available under the BSD licence.
>
> Use this tag if you have a question about using one of its features, including but not limited to:
>
> - Execution of SSH command, SFTP or SCP functionality
> - Remote, dynamic and local port forwarding
> - Shell/Terminal implementation.
> - any of the key exchange, encryption or hash methods
> - use of the OCKS4, SOCKS5 and/or HTTP Proxy
>
> The library can be used on any of these frameworks:
>
> - .NET Framework 3.5; 4.0
> - Silverlight 4; 5
> - Windows Phone 7.1; 8.0
>
> Make sure to either tag or indicate clearly for which framework the answers you're looking for should fit.
>
> The stable version [2013.4.7](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/104648) is also available as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/). There are also beta versions available. Make sure to include the version number you use in your question.
>
> - [Project homepage](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/)
> - [Download](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/104648)
> - [Documentation](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/documentation)
>
> <sup>above text is based on the content found on the project website</sup>

Comment: So your suggestion is: "we keep the stolen version, and if you don't like it, give us something better"? Sad.

Comment: That content is stolen. Stolen as in illegal, as in the authors have no given SO as a platform or the user putting it in permission to relicense and/or post it. Keeping it is simply not an option.

Comment: @fdreger where does it say *we keep the stolen version*?