# How to handle tag wikis with promotional content

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Ran across this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10225086) for a tag wiki, which seemed to me a little bit on the promotional side, and not entirely constructive as a tag (especially the part about the feature getting you new friends).

Looking back at some other of the tag edits by that user, I came across other horrors, like this (twice edited) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9635771). I don't really know if he's trying to advertise something, or just blindly copying it from some promotional web site, but either way I thought it had to stop, or in the latter case - at least be migrated to movies.stackexchange.

I tried flagging one of the questions with this tag for a mod, explaining the above, but it got declined because "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention", which I didn't entirely understand but seemed like a polite way to tell me to get lost.

So, ultimately, since all the reviewers who accepted these edits, as well as one moderator at least, seem to disagree, I was wondering - am I being too hard on some poor user trying to earn his fast rep? Or should SO have some tag wiki standards?

I have read Jeff's post [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), but it only left me more confused, if a tag is really supposed to be a "sales pitch", what are the limits? Could someone simply add some ascii art monkey eating waffles?

Comment: He just copy/pasted the Readme.md file of the github project.  Maybe the flippant style of the project author sends an appropriate signal to whomever considers depending on it.

Comment: When he said, *Think of it as a sales pitch*, that didn't mean that they are supposed to be literal advertising. He said it as guidance on how you should explain to users when to use a tag. So similar to how an ad might say, "For all your lawn care needs, go to [STORE NAME]", a tag wiki might say, "For questions about the use and extension of [APP API], use this tag."

Comment: I suspect the reason your flag was declined was because they'd expect you (or anyone else seeing it) to edit it themselves to fix it.

Comment: @BSMP, I'm afraid I lack the expertise in js to fix these tags, so it's good that someone here could fix them. The flag however was meant to ask the mod for some intervention (notifying the user that it's a bad habit)

Comment: @Leeor - I didn't realize at the time I made my comment that tag wikis were harder to deal with than edits on posts. And I agree that it makes sense to want someone to talk to the user since they've done this a few times.

Comment: [tag:spotfire] is another one

Comment: @C8H10N4O2, well, at least this one was informative, even if it sounds like an ad, so according to the answers here it's legit - maybe a simple `source: [link]` attribution is enough. Judging by the comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8833618), he probably wasn't aware he was doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your concern is legit. Those wiki's are awful and a blatant copy without attribution.

I noticed one of the reviewers of an edit was in the same chat room as I so after some discussion we decided to fix what is broken. Edits went out for:

- [yargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yargs)
- [tabletop.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabletop.js)

Let me elaborate a bit on how I read Jeff's guidance.

- The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag
  This is meant to be the elevator pitch for the tag on Stack Overflow. Why is the tag important, in which context can it be used.
- Concentrate on what a tag means to your community
  This does mean that the marketing speak can be avoided. But it can cover links to tutorials, documentation, guidance, FAQ's.
- Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag
  This mostly forgotten and I find this the hardest part to write for a tag. I normally look at the questions already tagged with it or study some of the documentation or concept to figure out what is relevant in the scope of Stack Overflow. If I can I try to make a bullet list of topics that a question can have and indicate if there are topics that definitely shouldn't be asked at all.

In the end I always link to the site(s) where I got the content from.

A couple of examples from my own are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3957726), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3957400), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311390/578411)

I'm not sure why the moderator declined your flag but I think they did that in error. Although the reason they chose might be valid the problem with tag wiki and excerpts is that only a couple of us have enough rep to instantly fix a broken window. We can't easy rollback wrong edits. In my ideal world moderators should be more careful when flags are raised about wiki content as the community members have less capabilities to proper moderate them.

Comment: Thanks for fixing these tags. I tried sampling the rest and didn't find anything too bad, so I guess that story is done. Anyhow - I completely agree with how you describe tag wikis (i'd also suggest showing other related tags, explaining when they'd be better), but someone should definitely put this in the help center.