# Adding the [transformers] tag for the transformers Python library

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I propose to add the [transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformers) tag to link to questions related to the excellent [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) library. I could not add it myself since it is too closely related to the existing [transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformer) tag, yet very different in what it entails.

[transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformer) involves an architecture, whereas [transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformers) is a library. Alternative tagnames are suggested below.

---

Answered questions per [#252945](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work/252945#252945):

**Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate**

- [Get probability of multi-token word in MASK position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435020/get-probability-of-multi-token-word-in-mask-position)
- [How to do multiclass classification with Hugging Face transformers using BERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144841/how-to-do-multiclass-classification-with-hugging-face-transformers-using-bert)
- [BertTokenizer - when encoding and decoding sequences extra spaces appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979779/berttokenizer-when-encoding-and-decoding-sequences-extra-spaces-appear)
- [Code example in Hugging Face Pytorch-Transformers quickstart documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891759/code-example-in-hugging-face-pytorch-transformers-quickstart-documentation)
- [Distill bert and svm for text classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383390/distill-bert-and-svm-for-text-classification?r=SearchResults)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151118/problems-with-pytorch-bert-on-google-cloud-ml-engine
- [Text generation using huggingface's distilbert models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59240668/text-generation-using-huggingfaces-distilbert-models)
- [BERT performing worse than word2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786929/bert-performing-worse-than-word2vec)

There are many more. Searching for "Hugging Face" or simply going through the posts that are tagged as [transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformer) often mention or use the "transformers" library.

**Explain why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow**

The field of natural language processing is evolving quickly. Since the end of 2017, but especially in late 2018 and 2019, many new transformer models came out. These models are created by different companies and research groups, making it hard for users to get their hands on specific models and implementations. That's where the "transformers" library comes in: it unifies many transformer models in one easy-to-use library. The library concerns natural language processing, the transformer architecture, PyTorch, [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), and Python, making it perfectly suited for Stack Overflow.

**Explain how the tag helps in categorizing and finding those questions**

Because "transformers" is not the only library out there that provides transformer models, it is a good idea to create this tag to distinguish itself from others like [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flair) (has a SO tag) and [fairseq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fairseq). That way, users of the library can specifically tag the library that they are using for their experiments.

**Provide an initial tag excerpt and wiki for the new tag.**

Short excerpt:

> Transformers is a Python library that implements transformer NLP models in
> PyTorch and TensorFlow.

Wiki:

> [`transformers`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) is a natural language processing (NLP) library that
> implements many state-of-the-art transformer models in Python using
> PyTorch and TensorFlow. It is created and maintained by HuggingFace.
> The library is available through package managers, and it is open-sourced on
> [GitHub](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers). The library was formerly known as pytorch-transformers and before
> that as pytorch-pretrained-bert.

**Propose a good fitting name for the tag as they are always lowercase, don't take spaces and have a maximum length of 35 characters.**

[transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformers) or, alternatively,  `transformers` (which the developers often use themselves - the emoji is the "Hugging Face" emoji, which is their company name).

The latter might be a better fit to better distinguish between the existing [transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformer) tag.

Alternatively, from a discussion in the comments, [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers) is suitable as well and is easier to distinguish from [transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformer) for users.

---

I created the tag [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers) and added the excerpt and wiki as posted above. Even though the review process is still not complete, one reviewer (David Maze) rejected the tag with the comment "This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source." I'm not sure how this is possible other than that it is a copy from this here Meta post. It feels like the reject is a mistake because I wrote that content myself and it seems quite specific and correct.

Comment: I don't think the emoji is enough to prevent people who want the existing transformer tag from choosing this one instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson Concerning the argument that adding tags that differ by one letter causes too much work seems counter-intuitive to what are tags are for. The longer SO exist, the more technologies will exist, and there's only a finite number of names and concepts (cf. scss vs css). Tags are exactly designed to distinguish between different items.

Comment: What about `huggingface-transformers`?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/ suggests that multiple words are difficult to make overlap/guessable

Comment: huggingface-transformers sounds much better to me. Much less chance of it being mistaken for anything else.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have submitted the suggested tag to the review queue. I hope that that was the correct procedure to keep this moving.

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you please comment on why you rejected the proposed tag? "Content from an external source" seems quite vague and incorrect. See the edit to the OP.

Comment: DavidMaze has not commented on this question and won't therefore be notified by your comment. I'm notified instead because I'm the only commenter other than you.

Comment: Hm. I suppose it would be useful to have a tagging system on meta but I'm sure the pros and cons of that have already been discussed.

Comment: The wiki better explains for which cases / questions the tag can be added. I've approved that 1st revision as I see no evidence that the wiki text was plagiarized from anywhere else except your own answer here (although it is easy to see where you got inspired)

Comment: Not sure if you need inspiration but my answer here might help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312219/578411

Comment: I wonder if David Maze did what I just did when reviewing your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24933373): I searched for "library that implements many state-of-the-art transformer models in Python using PyTorch and Tensorflow", and found it verbatim on the internet - on this question. I did see that you wrote this question so clearly you've not plagiarised yourself - maybe David didn't?

Answer (score 3):

We now have the [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers) tag for this.

My reservations about the absolute ridiculousness of that name aside (and, yeah, it's *way* better than having an actual emoji there), that does seem to be, as stated in the question, [the actual name of the organization](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index) that develops this library, so I guess it's appropriate.

I also renamed the existing [transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformer) tag to [transformer-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformer-model) (preserving the former as a synonym of the latter) to hopefully address any potential ambiguities.

Hugging faces all around, I suppose. (What's a hugging *face*?)

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a [spacy-pytorch-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy-pytorch-transformers) for that library already, unless pytorch has more than one transformers library. Perhaps you could edit it to provide some usage guidance.

If that's not the right tag then why not use its name as a guide for the tag you want to create. Make it more specific so its obvious its the right one for the library. E.g [pytorch-tensorflow-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch-tensorflow-transformers)

At any rate creating tags that differ by 1 letter would simply create permanent retagging work.

Comment: That is a different library. It is a wrapper by one library (spaCy) over the aforementioned `transformers` library. I have updated my OP and also suggest a more distinct tag, including an emoji which the developers also use in their documentation, ` transformers`.