# The [huggingface-transformers] tag should not be a NLP Collective tag (anymore)

Tags: discussion, tags, collectives, nlp-collective

[Hugging Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugging_Face) offers transformers for vision, audio, etc., and it is not purely NLP-based anymore.

There are is a variety of questions that use [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers), but are not NLP questions:

- Vision

  - [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers) and "image" [search 230 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhuggingface-transformers%5D+image)
  - e.g. [How do you train Huggingface Maskformer for instance segmentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74975964/how-do-you-train-huggingface-maskformer-for-instance-segmentation)
- Audio

  - Search of [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers) and "audio": [55 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhuggingface-transformers%5D+audio)
  - e.g [Ffmpeg - transform mulaw 8000khz audio buffer data into valid bytes format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651663/ffmpeg-transform-mulaw-8000khz-audio-buffer-data-into-valid-bytes-format)
- more cases

---

[Inside the NLP  Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=collective%3A%22NLP%22+%5Bhuggingface-transformers%5D) most questions, that should be in the NLP collective, have appropriate tag combinations to stay there even if [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers) is removed.

Therefore, it is safe and appropriate in my opinion to remove the [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers) from associated tags of the NLP collective.

---

---

###### Initial discussion about [transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformers) and [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers)

[Adding the [transformers] tag for the transformers Python library](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392356/adding-the-transformers-tag-for-the-transformers-python-library)

Comment: Sounds like [tag:huggingface-transformers] is becoming too broad...

Comment: @Cerbrus IMO not at all. We don't judge Python to be a tag that's too broad because you can do many things with Python. The same goes for transformers. It's a clearly-defined library with a single type of model, as I understand it.

Comment: Ohh, got it– despite "huggingface-transformers" sounding like a _category_, it just refers to [the one, single library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/huggingface-transformers/info). That makes sense.

Comment: @zcoop98 probably that tag-wiki should be updated also